# How to set a counter within ForEach-Object Parallel - PowerShell 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0, foreach-object

I have a int variable defined outside the foreach block, trying to set it within the block and access it outside. However, when I run this script, I get below error. It seems to be a basic thing but I am new to PowerShell.

**Error :** The '++' operator works only on variables or on properties.

**Script** :

```
[int]$ErrorCount = 0
1..3 | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 40 -Parallel  {
            $using:ErrorCount++
}

$FinishMessage = "Errors: {0}" -f $ErrorCount
echo $FinishMessage
```

Comment: Do you realy need `using`? I think that is causing the problem...

Comment: I think, to avoid scoping issue ```using``` keyword should be used within Parallel statement to access variables outside the statement. However, without ```using``` the counter increments to 1 for each thread (remains 1 - this is another issue) and still display as a 0,

Comment: Seems to be a more serious multi threading problem as the `$errorCount` isn't threadsafely shared for writing. Would you be able to return the count of errors at the end of a Foreach ScriptBlock? `1..3| % -parallel {sleep 5;return $_}| % {$ErrorCount += $_ }`

Answer (score 1):

A more typical idiom would be to return some properties:

```
1..40 | ForEach-Object -ThrottleLimit 40 -Parallel {
  sleep 1
  [pscustomobject]@{Error = $true }
} | measure error

Count             : 40
Average           :
Sum               :
Maximum           :
Minimum           :
StandardDeviation :
Property          : Error
```